# Updating state in componentDidUpdate causes infinite loop

Tags: react-native

I red about `getDerivedStateFromProps` but it seems that this not what I need. I am executing the code above and infinite loop occurs. How can I prevent that? Need to update quiz questions on every update. The code:

```
async componentDidUpdate() {
    await this.questions();
  }

  questions = async () => {
    const questions = await Promise.all(
      this.props.navigation.getParam("quizzes").subQuiz.map(async (quiz) => {
        const quizQuestions = await firebase
          .firestore()
          .collection("questions")
          .where("quizId", "==", quiz.uid)
          .get();

        return quizQuestions.docs.map((quizQ) => {
          return { uid: quizQ.id, ...quizQ.data() };
        });
      })
    );

    const quizzes = this.props.navigation.getParam("quizzes").subQuiz;
    let final = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < quizzes.length; i++) {
      const quiz = quizzes[i];
      const quizQuestions = questions[i];
      final.push([
        {
          quiz: {
            ...quiz,
            quizQuestions: {
              ...quizQuestions,
            },
          },
        },
      ]);
    }

    this.setState({ quizzes: final }, () => {
      console.log("TUKASME", this.state.quizzes[0].quiz);
    });
  };
```

Thankful for every advice!react-

Comment: `componentDidUpdate` is called whenever props or state change. If you're updating state whenever that's called, you're going to call `componentDidUpdate` again, hence the loop. What is your motivation for putting things in `componentDidUpdate`?

Comment: Are you putting it there to catch when `props.navigation.getParams('quizzes')` changes?

Comment: I wan't to retrieve the questions related to that quiz when user clicks on the quiz. And create an array to set it in the state for later usage in the render.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to only do the update if `props.navigation.getParams('quizzes')` is different from last time you updated. One way you can do this is by storing the `quizzes` parameter in an instance variable:

```
componentDidUpdate() {
  const currentParam = this.props.navigation.getParam("quizzes");
  if (currentParam !== this.lastQuizzes) {
    this.lastQuizzes = currentParam;
    this.questions();
  }
}
```

If you're feeling ambitious and want to convert to a functional components pattern with hooks, they've got a much easier technique to conditionally update using `useEffect`:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

function MyComponent({ navigation }) {
  const [state, setState] = useState();
  const quizzesParam = navigation.getParam('quizzes');
  useEffect(() => {
    updateQuizzes();
  }, [quizzesParam]);

  async function updateQuizzes() {
    const questions = await Promise.all(
      quizzesParam.subQuiz.map(async (quiz) => {
        const quizQuestions = await firebase
          .firestore()
          .collection("questions")
          .where("quizId", "==", quiz.uid)
          .get();

        return quizQuestions.docs.map((quizQ) => {
          return { uid: quizQ.id, ...quizQ.data() };
        });
      })
    );

    const quizzes = quizzesParam.subQuiz;
    let final = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < quizzes.length; i++) {
      const quiz = quizzes[i];
      const quizQuestions = questions[i];
      final.push([
        {
          quiz: {
            ...quiz,
            quizQuestions: {
              ...quizQuestions,
            },
          },
        },
      ]);
    }

    setState({ ...state, quizzes: final });
  }

  // Render...
}
```

With this pattern, the effect only fires on initial mount or if the values in the array change.